# Where can I find the firebaseui css stylesheet?

Tags: css, firebase-authentication, documentation, cdn, firebaseui

I installed Firebase in my react.js app, installed FirebaseUI, and got Google sign-in to work properly. However, there is absolutely no css stylesheet being applied to the Google signin button. I looked at the docs here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui and visited the cdn link for the firebaseui.css file here https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/4.6.1/firebaseui.css but it just returns page not found. Where would I be able to find the firebase UI css stylesheet to apply to my firebaseui installation?

Also, I had to slightly edit the docs' (same doc page link as above) instruction code and instead of writing

```
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
  signInOptions: [
    {
      provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      requireDisplayName: false
    }
  ]
});
```

I had to change it to

```
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
  signInOptions: [
    {
      provider: firebase.firebase_.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      requireDisplayName: false
    }
  ]
});
```

to get to the correct firebase .PROVDER_ID variable. Is this because the firebase documentation is out of date? Has anyone else experienced a similar issue while using firebase and firebaseUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link in the documentation is stale.  When you come across things like this, you can use the "send feedback" button at the top of any page in the Firebase docs to let the team know.

You will want to use the links in the documentation on the [Firebase UI GitHub repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) instead.  They start with "https://www.gstatic.com".